# FragmentContainerView as the navigation view in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a fragment that I sometimes want to display as a full screen and sometimes as the contents of the burger menu.

I have setup an activity with a burger menu like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.SomeActivity"
    >
<!--    tools:openDrawer="left"-->

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/my_menu_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.ui.WhateverFragment"
        android:background="@color/someBackgroundColor"
        tools:layout="@layout/brand_feed_fragment"
        android:clickable="true" />
<!-- clickable had no effect actually -->
    .... activity UI here

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `WhateverFragment` has a RecyclerView and in each item I add a `OnClickListener`. When presented as a fragment of full screen activity that listener is invoked.

However, when i tap anywhere in my 'drawer' then it simply closes and my onclicklistener is not invoked in my fragment.

What am I missing?

Comment: The drawer should be listed last within the `<DrawerLayout>` tags in order for it to receive touch events properly. That is, move your `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>` to after everything in `activity UI here`.

Comment: @MikeM. this worked! thank you so much :) if you add this as answer, I will accept it

Comment: No problem. I'm good, though. :-) Nothin' huge. Please feel free to finish this up however you'd like. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Mike-M:

The drawer should be listed last within the `<DrawerLayout>` tags in order for it to receive touch events properly. That is, move your `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>` to after everything in `activity UI here`.